# How could I do transitions between elements after I sort an array of "images"?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, reactjs, transition

I have an array of objects `images` which looks like that:

```
images= [
{
  url: "http://image.com/image.jpg
  name: xxx
  tag: xxx
},
{...},
...]
```

and I use a `.map()` on this array to display.

I already use `CSSTransition` for the transition when the image appears and disappears but now I would like to know how could I do an animation for the reordering between elements after I sort the elements ?

I would like doing something like in the `react-stack-grid` example when you click on shuffle.
I do not really know where to start for this kind of transition between elements.The main difference in my gallery is that I only use elements with the same size so I don't have the "masonry" effect.

I actually call the elements like that:

```
<TransitionGroup component={null}>
  {
    array.map((element, index) =>
      <CSSTransition classNames="card" key={'key'+index}>
        <GalleryImage className='gallery-thumbnail' element={element}/>
      </CSSTransition>
    )
  }
</TransitionGroup>
```

the object `GalleryImage` is not very complicated, it's just an image with some information over it.

Does anyone know how I can do this effect of reordering elements ?
Or maybe someone would have some clues?

Comment: How are you sorting? What CSS are you using? Have you looked at something like Metafizzy Isotope? The sort demo: https://isotope.metafizzy.co/.

Comment: i use the Array.sort() function with a function i made than can sort with 3 attributes (the path of the element you want to sort on, true or false for ascending or descending and a function if you want to sort again on another attributes (the "then" sort)). For CSS i use Sass. I didn't saw Metafizzy Isotope but if i'm not wrong it's not free so it's not good for my case :(. I would like to do this on myself for improve my skill in making low level components.